# Example of a keyframed curve editor control for an animation tool?

Tags: wpf, animation, user-interface, controls, curve

Are there any examples of creating a kind of keyframed curve editor control in WPF as typically seen in animation software? For example, here's one in Gamedev Animation Studio, the large top right control:

[image]

I doubt there are any ready-made controls out there, but maybe there's something available I can use as a base?